# How effective is guest-blogging for SEO?

Tags: seo, blog, guest-blogging

I was wondering how much time to devote to guest-blogging.  It is pretty consuming and one person can only do a few per day max. And often you just get a link in the bottom of the post.

Is it really beneficial to SEO? And if so, are there any particular tricks or pitfalls to it?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? The SEO "effectiveness" of guest blogging depends on how you do it. What kind of sites are you guest-blogging for? What's the quality of your blog posts? If you're cranking out multiple blog posts each day, then you're either an exceptionally gifted and insightful writer or your blog posts are little more than blog spam. Even professional bloggers can't crank out that volume of content on their own sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you get the backlink to your site, you *may* get some rep if you're guest blogging on a highly trafficked or influential site, but that may be all you end up getting out of it.

It may depend a lot on the rules that you have to follow on the host site. Maybe they'll let you backlink to your site *and* provide a follow link to your twitter account? Maybe they'll let you share in some of the proceeds from any ad activity on that page?

It would probably help to start out by determining what *you* want to get out of the process. If you want to simply amass a lot of backlinks to your site, commenting on a lot of similar blogs to your own may be just as effective as guest blogging. If your blog does not get a lot of user feedback on posts you publish and you are keen on finding out how effective your writing style is, guest blogging on a more highly trafficked site could be good for you.